# Can't use Reddit on Tor - What do I do?

Tags: exit-relays, blocked

I can't sign up for Reddit because I'm unable to open the reCAPTCHA. It said my computer may be sending automating queries, which I'm pretty sure is because I'm connecting from Tor and they are recieving a lot of traffic from Tor.

How do I circumvent this? Are there unlisted Tor exit nodes I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Restart Tor until it works. You probably got a bad exit node, with bad traffic. Restarting Tor will get you new circuit

Please note some sites will intentionally block all Tor traffic, in which case there is nothing you can do